# Android bus tracking

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I just need some guidance. I am trying to create a bus tracking application.The intention of the app is the traveler can know the current bus location and upcoming bus stops. Of course we can know the current location through google map. But my intention is to give user a new UI that will display only bus stops which are in some linear line with some marker(Please refer image).[image: Tracking]

I have the data of all stops of bus. My question is how can I club this data to realtime tracking with gps.I can fetch the coordinates of these bus stops. But how I can connect it with map and give user live tracking? NB: The image is from indian rail tracking. I dont know how they manage to do that. Please give me some insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the blue print of the map and with that blue print you will have to map each and every point onto your custom map view. Real map will work like a backend server and your map will be a front end of it.

Comment: It means your app will have to have all the raw data from the actual map then with that data you will construct your own mapview with all the functionalities you want in it. You will have to get raw data from the map and then create some meta data about the data obtained. You will then map that data according to that meta data in your custom mapview.

Comment: Thanks bro..Is there any other workaround to accomplish this?

Comment: Let's take the example of this train tracking map. This app first of all gets the location of all the station and create a custom map-view by mapping those locations on that view. Then it will get the locations of moving trains and map them on this custom maps as markers to those trains.

Comment: Creating this from scratch can be very hectic and complex why don't you extend the google maps apis just as careem and uber have done. This is a workaround.

Comment: Bro i thought it will be more useful to user with less data

Comment: If i integreate google map , how can i mark all these stops in that? suppose if i provide staring and ending bus stops? will that be easy?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186659/discussion-between-wijdan-and-androdevil).